# How to create a filter using input and FormControl?

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I created an input that filters and displays the data according to what the user typed, but I encounter two problems:

1. I could only do it using ngModel and this model is deprecated in Angular 11.
2. When selecting the found value, the FormControl does not update the Input.

If it is necessary to use the FormControl.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `ReactiveFormsModule`. Refer to the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) for examples.

To address your problems:

> 1. I could only do it using ngModel and this model is deprecated in Angular 11.

You need to create a `FormGroup` instance with a form control for the input element. For example,

```
@Component({ ... })
export class SearchInputComponent implements OnInit {
  form!: FormGroup;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.form = new FormGroup({
      query: new FormControl('')
    });
  }

}
```

Now you can attach the instance of the `FormGroup` to a form element in your template (e.g., `[formGroup]="form"`). Next, add `formControlName="query"` to the input element.

> 2. When selecting the found value, the FormControl does not update the Input.

That's because you don't have an event listener attached to the `div` element. Add the `(click)` and `(keydown.enter)` directives to the parent `div`. Make sure to add the `tabindex="0"` attribute so the user can use the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key to traverse the results and press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key to select a result.

Here's a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-search-input-example?file=src%2Finput-search-filter%2Finput-search-filter.component.ts) for reference.

Hope this helps.

Comment: `formControl` can be used directly, without wrapping it with `formGroup`!

Comment: Indeed. There are various ways to solve this problem. I only provided one.

Answer (score 0):

for question 1: Delete the ngModel, you don't need it - the formControl has it all.
if you need the value of the control - simply do `control.value`, for example in the filter - `let item of items | filter: term.value`

for question 2: it will not update until you'll update it - add `click` event to the `div` that holds the `item`

```
<div (click)="updateControl(item.title)"> 
   <h1>{{item.title}}</h1>
   ...
</div>
```

and something like this to .ts file

```
updateControl(title: string) {
   this.control.setValue(title)
}
```

hope it answer your questions :)